# Chrome Driver takes a lot of time to load page, BeautifulSoup Does same with processing data

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

I have a webpage to scrape data from

```
https://rock30games.com/results?depts=&store=&description=&upc=&action=SEARCH
```

Chrome driver gives timeout exception. While, if i use

```
requests.get('https://rock30games.com/results?depts=&store=&description=&upc=&action=SEARCH)
```

and use BesutifulSoup, it takes hell a lot of time. Is there any way to tacke this problem? If so, how?

Comment: Manually it took more than 2 mins, I think even with automation it will take same amount of time

Comment: The page just takes forever to load, and the API takes just as long. Your script can't go faster than the page can load so I don't think it's possible to reduce this time.

If you want to avoid the chromedriver timeout, increase it, use `driver.set_page_load_timeout(number_of_seconds)`

Comment: It occurs to me one way to speed things up a bit would be to use a headless browser, that makes things run faster in my experience